# Making a proxy/service class more generic

Tags: c#, generics

I have 4 classes that I have to modify each time I want to make a call to the database, and the process is getting ridiculous. I'm wondering if there's an easy way to simplify the process.

I have a calling class such that:

```
public ResponseObjectA getClients() {
     RequestObjectA req = new RequestObjectA();
     ResponseObjectA res = ProxyClass.GetClients(request);
}

public ResponseObjectB getVendors() {
     RequestObjectB req = new RequestObjectB();
     ResponseObjectB res = ProxyClass.GetVendors(request);
}
```

then in my ProxyClass:

```
public static ResponseObjectA getClients(RequestObjectA request) [
    ResponseObjectA res = new ResponseObjectA();
    res = ServiceClass.GetClients(request);
}

public static ResponseObjectB getVendors(RequestObjectB request) [
    ResponseObjectB res = new ResponseObjectB();
    res = ServiceClass.GetVendors(request);
}
```

then in my ServiceClass:

```
public ResponseObjectA getClients(RequestObjectA request) [
    ResponseObjectA res = new ResponseObjectA();
    DALClass.GetClients(request, res);
}

public ResponseObjectB getVendors(RequestObjectB request) [
    ResponseObjectB res = new ResponseObjectB();
    DALClass.GetVendors(request, res);
}
```

finally my DALClass:

```
public void getClients(RequestObjectA request, ResponseObjectA response) [
   ..perform sql stuff..
}

public void getVendors(RequestObjectB request, ResponseObjectB response) [
    ..perform sql stuff
}
```

Do any of you see the problem here if I'm going to add ResponseObjectC and RequestObjectC if I'm going to make a call called GetSales? It's another 5 more updates.

I simplified these methods just to illustrate the point, each method does do something useful. The problem I have is the repetitiveness of copying methods and changing one piece of code. I was wondering if there's a way to do a generic type for the ProxyClass and ServiceClass so I don't have to modify them. Just the calling class and the DALClass.

**Side note:**
ResponseObjectA and ResponseObjectB are both child classes of BaseResponse.. likewise for RequestObjectA and RequestObjectB are both child classes of BaseRequest.

**One solution:**
I thought about was having all the method names called "Handle" and use method overloading.

Like the end result of the DALClass would be having the following signatures:

```
 public void Handler(RequestObjectA, ResponseObjectA) { }
 public void Handler(RequestObjectB, ResponseObjectB) { }
```

but I'm not sure what the Proxy and Service classes would look like to verify that the correct handler is being called.

Comment: Looks like you have a copy/paste bug in your posted proxy code. First method should be `getClients()`, no? Also, why does the proxy code instantiate a response object only to throw it away? Also, why isn't it the DAL that creates the response object (versus your service class creating the instance to be filled in, as it seems to be now)?

Comment: haha you're right. that's why I hate copying and pasting.. and I make the same mistake over and over in my code. It's frustrating. That why I want to eliminate this process.

Comment: As for the DAL not creating the response object.. no idea. This isn't my design pattern.. and the guys who made it never took the time to think things through.. so I'm suffering the consequences of it. I would like an easier way to correcting this process given what the state looks like as of now.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you could consolidate somewhat writing a generic method or two:

```
public static TResponse get<TRequest, TResponse>(TRequest request, Func<TRequest, TResponse> getter) 
    where TRequest : BaseRequest
    where TResponse : BaseResponse
{
    TResponse res = getter(request);
}
```

You would still need to write out each method, but they would be shorter, as you could abstract the common stuff out:

```
public static ResponseObjectA getClients(RequestObjectA request) {
    return get(request, ServiceClass.GetClients);
}

public static ResponseObjectB getVendors(RequestObjectB request) {
    return get(request, ServiceClass.GetVendors);
}
```

---

Also, if you haven't already, I would take a look to see whether [T4 templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd820614.aspx) wouldn't be useful -- it looks like they might be.  Instead of robo-coding the Proxy and Service classes, you could maintain something like a tuple list (name of method, request type, response type), and then write a T4 template that generates each of the classes with the various methods for each entry in the list.  (This is how the auto-generated code like service proxy and database entity classes get generated in Visual Studio.)

Answer (score 1):

The main problem you're going to run into is that web services don't support generics - they require concrete types.  Rather than trying to make all levels generic, I would instead look at where you have reusable *code* and try to refactor that into common classes (where you *may* be able to use generics further).

If you don't like copy/paste you could look into creating *templates* that would generate the majority of the common structure and code for you - you;d just have to fill in the specifics for the new type.

Comment: sadly none of them use common code. There are just code that looks similar. I might indeed have to look into T4 templates for this one.

Comment: I was going off of the "changing one piece of code" comment.  If there isn't much common code then generics certainly isn't going to help much.  Generics are meant to reuse code, not method signatures.

Comment: gotcha.. I was thinking "generics" because I want the process to be "generic".. haha. Thanks for the advice.